# Using the MVC [Authorize] attibute without a user Db

Tags: authentication, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, forms-authentication, .net-framework-version

I have very simple MVC website (.net Framework - not core) and I want to protect one of the controllers using the [Authorize] attribute. Forcing the user to login before they can call any of the methods in that controller. - Can I do this without using a database?

```
    [Authorize]
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        // action methods
    }
```

This is a single user login I don't need roles etc. The requirements mean I can hard code the credentials in my code. So I can create a controller and a login page, but how do I set the user to be authorized?

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string userName, string password)
        {
            if (UserLoginCorrect(userName, password))
            {
                //Code here to make current user Authroised.
            }


            return View();
        }
```

In addition to that how do I remove this authrisation when the user logs out.

Comment: Question. How can the user 'log in' if there is no DB to check their credentials?

Comment: They are hard coded... if password = "passwordhere"

Comment: What does your user class look like?

Comment: No user class... just two strings passed in.

Comment: Could you not just add a custom actionFilter on the Index of the home and when the user navigates to it, do a check to see whether the password and username they enter are correct?

Comment: I have worked it out... answer to follow